# Get String value from Enum in .net core Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a policy based .net core MVC application, in which only Authorized user has access to any particular menu. I used `[Authorize(Policy = "MenuName")]` attribute for every controllers. But I want to generalize it with one `Enum`, where all the Menus are listed in one `Enum` and use it in `Authorize` attribute instead of a static string (`"MenuName"`).

```
public enum MenuEnum
    {
        [Description("Menu1")]
        Dashboard,
        [Description("Menu2")]
        Help,
        [Description("Menu3")]
        About
    }
```

and I want to use it like `[Authorize(Policy = MenuEnum.Dashboard)]` instead of static string `[Authorize(Policy = "Dashboard")]`. Can we have any way to generalize `Authorize` attribute with Enum?

Answer (score 1):

I have a extensions method and I use it to read the name of display attribute

```cs
        public static string ToDisplay(this Enum value, DisplayProperty property = DisplayProperty.Name)
        {

            var attribute = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())
                .GetCustomAttributes<DisplayAttribute>(false).FirstOrDefault();

            if (attribute == null)
                return value.ToString();

            var propValue = attribute.GetType().GetProperty(property.ToString()).GetValue(attribute, null);
            return propValue.ToString();
        }
```

And you can use it this way
replace Description attribute with DisplayAttribute and set propery Name

```cs
public enum MenuEnum
    {
        [Display(Name="Menu1")]
        Dashboard,
        [Display(Name="Menu2")]
        Help,
        [Display(Name="Menu3")]
        About
    }
```

```cs
[Authorize(Policy=MenuEnum.About.ToDisplay())]
```

Comment: Thank you for a response. Can you please let me know what is DisplayProperty? Do I need any reference to add?

Comment: You must use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace to use the DisplayAttribute. You can use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to get help. If I answered the correct answer to your question, please choose my answer as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own AuthorizeAttribute.

1.AuthorizeMenuPolicyAttribute

```
 public class AuthorizeMenuPolicyAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeMenuPolicyAttribute(MenuEnum Policy) : base(typeof(AuthorizeMenuPolicyFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { Policy };
    }
}
```

2.AuthorizeMenuPolicyFilter

```
 public class AuthorizeMenuPolicyFilter: IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorization;
    public MenuEnum _policy { get;  set; }
    public AuthorizeMenuPolicyFilter(MenuEnum policy, IAuthorizationService authorization)
    {
        _policy = policy;
        _authorization = authorization;
    }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string description = GetEnumDescription(_policy);

        var authorized = await _authorization.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, description);
        if (authorized.Succeeded)
        {
            return;
        }
       context.Result = new ForbidResult();
       return;

    }

    public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];

        if (attributes != null && attributes.Any())
        {
            return attributes.First().Description;
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

3.Add Policy you want on Startup

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Menu1", policy =>
                    policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                        context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "menu1")));

        });
```

4.Authorization based on string value from Enum

```
[AuthorizeMenuPolicy(MenuEnum.Dashboard)]
```